# Is there a way to insert variable in regexp?

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to use regex pattern based on user input which is saved in a variable. That variable will then be used in a regex search pattern.

Here is some part of the code that is working if city is hard coded to regex pattern:

```
    //city.txt has the following input information:

    //Boston 100 AA BB
    //Chicago 200 CC DD


    //Get user input

    fmt.Print("Enter city: ")
    scanner.Scan()
    city:= scanner.Text()

    //Read file from text and convert to string

    citylist, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("city.txt")
    convertcitytostring:= string(citylist)

    //Use regexp to search the citylist(str)

    search1:= regexp.MustCompile(`Boston\s\S.*`)
    search2:= search1.FindString(convertcitytostring)

    //Convert results to []string

    search3:= strings.Fields(search2)

    //Print

    fmt.Printf("%v %T", search3, search3)
    fmt.Printf("\n")

    //Output:
    //[Boston 100 AA BB] []string
```

What I would like to do is use variable "city" instead of hard coded pattern:

```
    search1:= regexp.MustCompile(`city\s\S.*`)
    search2:= search1.FindString(convertSitestoString)
```

Comment: regexp.MustCompile(fmt.Sprintf(`%s\s\S.*`,city))

Comment: Wow that was so easy for you! It worked like a charm, thank you!. I kept looking for a solution in the regexp package, it was in fmt all along. Sorry for being noob. Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to achieve? And how does the input look like?

Comment: You could also just do `regexp.MustCompile(city + ``\s\S.*``)`.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I have a very specific problem - I would like to insert variable content in to regexp which I honestly do not know. And had a hard time searching for similar problem. I am new to Go and to programming in general. This is just a part of the code which I am asking user to input a city, then it will populate the number of registered voters, land area, etc which is stored in a static file in this case, city.txt.

Comment: Personally, I would rather parse the file on startup and answer from RAM than dynamically compiling regexes. The very least would be to create a `map[string]*regexp.Regexp` and reuse compiled regexes over the runtime of your program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The input to `regexp.MustCompile` is a string. Just concatenate your variable with the rest of the pattern;

```golang
city := "Boston"
search1:= regexp.MustCompile(regexp.QuoteMeta(city) + `\s\S.*`)
```

Make sure to escape user-input (`regexp.QuoteMeta`) to prevent special characters from being evaluated as a pattern.

Comment: Furthermore I would like to add that compiling a regexp is a relatively expensive operation.

Comment: shouldn't it be `regexp.QuoteMeta` ?